# Error converting json retrieved from API to C# class using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

2 parts to this question.

I am the owner of an API and if there is no data to return (based on business rules) the response is delivered like so:

```
var resp = new { error = "", code = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK, data = leads};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp);
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return Ok(json);
```

And when I call this in Postman, this is rendered as:

```
"{\"error\":\"\",\"code\":200,\"data\":[]}"
```

What is with the slashes?

My second part, which may or may not be fixed by fixing the slashes, is when I consume the API, and deserialize the response to an object, I receive the following error

> Error converting value "{"error":"","code":200,"data":[]}" to type 'DataTypes.IntegrationResponse'. Path '', line 1, position 43.

For those who need it, IntegrationResponse is:

```
public class IntegrationResponse
{
    public string error { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public List<IntegrationLead> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you serialize object with JsonConvert and then return `StringContent` when you can just return object and it will serialize it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd make this a comment if I could, need more rep.  That said -

Try making `List<IntegrationLead>` an `InegrationLead[]` and all the slashes are to escape the quotes and you have an awesome name.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks bro. It's Friday and after posting this, I spotted that I was returning string (return Ok(...) instead of the response I created

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i will do this 
in APi

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
  return Json(new {foo="bar", baz="Blech"});
}
```

If you want to use JsonConverter and control how the data get serilized then

```
  public class JsonNetResult : ActionResult
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="JsonNetResult"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public JsonNetResult()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the content encoding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The content encoding.</value>
        public Encoding ContentEncoding { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the type of the content.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The type of the content.</value>
        public string ContentType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The data object.</value>
        public object Data { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Enables processing of the result of an action method by a custom type that inherits from the <see cref="T:System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The context in which the result is executed. The context information includes the controller, HTTP content, request context, and route data.</param>
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            response.ContentType = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ContentType) ? this.ContentType : "application/json";

            if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
            {
                response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
            }


            if (this.Data != null)
            {

                response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Data));

            }
        }
    }
```

> Blockquote

```
    public class CallbackJsonResult : JsonNetResult
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CallbackJsonResult"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="statusCode">The status code.</param>
        public CallbackJsonResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
        {
            this.Initialize(statusCode, null, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CallbackJsonResult"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="statusCode">The status code.</param>
        /// <param name="description">The description.</param>
        public CallbackJsonResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string description)
        {
            this.Initialize(statusCode, description, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CallbackJsonResult"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="statusCode">The status code.</param>
        /// <param name="data">The callback result data.</param>
        public CallbackJsonResult(object data, HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            this.ContentType = null;
            this.Initialize(statusCode, null, data);
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CallbackJsonResult"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="statusCode">The status code.</param>
        /// <param name="description">The description.</param>
        /// <param name="data">The callback result data.</param>
        public CallbackJsonResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string description, object data)
        {
            this.Initialize(statusCode, description, data);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="statusCode">The status code.</param>
        /// <param name="description">The description.</param>
        /// <param name="data">The callback result data.</param>
        private void Initialize(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string description, object data)
        {
            Data = new JsonData() { Success = statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK, Status = (int)statusCode, Description = description, Data = data };
        }
    }
}
```

> then create an extention

```
/// <summary>
/// return Json Action Result
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="o"></param>
/// <param name="JsonFormatting"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static CallbackJsonResult ViewResult<T>(this T o)
{
    return new CallbackJsonResult(o);
}
```

> No APi simple use the extention that you created

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
  return new { error = "", code = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK, data = leads}.ViewResult();
}
```